# Gmail on iPhone app : pictures broken

Tags: iphone, gmail

The native Gmail iPhone 4 app on my phone behaves weird, it is not showing pictures that come as attachment, when I click on the picture it starts downloading the picture but it displays those classic picture not available pic with a question mark. I tried deleting account and adding it again still no luck..

Any clue?

I'm on iOS 4.1

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the native Mail app, not Gmail, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything that officially says there's an iPhone file-size limitation, but I have noticed that over 3G, some larger pictures will not download to my mailbox. Try over WiFi or get [3G Unrestrictor](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.crashx.unrestrictor3g) and see what happens.